# Android, Espresso: Not found ImageView with tag end by "en"

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to find imageView with tag end by text "en".

My espresso test:

```
    @Test
public void testViewPagerSwipe() {
    onView(withId(R.id.containerLanguageEN)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.textViewNext)).perform(click());
    ImageView imageViewTour = (ImageView) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageViewTour);
    String tag = (String) imageViewTour.getTag();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "testViewPagerSwipe: tag = " + tag);
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.imageViewTour), withTagValue(is((Object) endsWith("en"))))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

This test print:

```
testViewPagerSwipe: tag = walkthrough_01_en
```

As you can see the tag of imageViewTour is **walkthrough_01_en**.

But the test is fail:

```
     android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException:

No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.myproject.android.dev:id/imageViewTour and with tag value: is <a string ending with "en">)
```

Why?